# Why does Antlr not generate a lexer java file?

Tags: java, antlr3, antlrworks

Antlr3 does not generate Mylexer.java. I use AntlrWorks...

when I have grammar starting like

grammar mylexer;

It does generate myParser.java

It looks like a simple thing..
I wonder what may be the reason..  and the solution...
I get no error message.

Comment: Could you at least provide an error message or little more information?

Comment: There is no error message!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way.
AntlrWorks 1.4 seems to have a bug. 
When I pressed ctrl+shift+G to generate it did not give an error message (in fact, I got that compilation was ok) and generated a parser file only.  The cursor was not on the first line of the source file when that happened.

WHen I pressed ctrl+shift+G in the first line, I got an error message and when I fixed those,
a lexer file was generated too.